# Build project without selecting it as the active scheme?

Tags: xcode, swift

In Visual Studio you can right-click on a project and build it. With XCode it seems as though one must select a project using the active scheme selector in the tool bar before you can build a target. Is it possible to leave the active scheme as is and build a different target?

Answer (score 1):

There is not really any such thing as "the active scheme". There is only the scheme that will be used the next time you build (or perform any other scheme action: build, run, test, profile, archive). That's the one that's selected in the toolbar.

If that scheme says to build a certain target, that is the target you'll build if you use Xcode's GUI interface to build.

It is not obvious to me what objection you could have to changing schemes, since this is exactly how to change what target you will build. It doesn't affect the interface in any way, for example. All you're doing is specifying what to build, which seems to be exactly what you want to do.

However, naturally you can always call `xcodebuild` to build any target (or scheme, for that matter), quite without regard to the Xcode interface.

Comment: If you roll over the tool bar selector it says, "Set the active scheme". ;) I want to be able to right click on a target and build it because its quicker. I find myself having to switch between targets because XCode is not always building dependent targets. Some targets even disappear from the tool bar selector. So you need to manage the schemas to make such a target visible before you can select it.

Comment: In fact I think it was building dependent targets but not always able to link them.